# Access another element immutably while mutating an element of a HashMap

Tags: rust

I'm working on a game that involves a bunch of `Beetle` objects stored in a `HashMap`. Each beetle has a position, and it can also have a target id which is the key for another beetle in the hash. If a beetle has a target, it needs to move toward the target each time the game loop executes.

I can't perform the lookup of the target's current position, because you can't have a mutable and immutable borrow at the same. I get that, but any ideas how to restructure for my specific case?

I think I'm just getting caught up in how easy this would be in pretty much any other language, I can't see the idiomatic Rust way to do it. Here's a pretty minimal but complete example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type Beetles = HashMap<i32, Beetle>;

struct Beetle {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    target_id: i32,
}

impl Beetle {
    fn new() -> Beetle {
        Beetle {
            x: 0.0,
            y: 0.0,
            target_id: -1,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut beetles: Beetles = HashMap::new();

    beetles.insert(0, Beetle::new());
    beetles.insert(1, Beetle::new());

    set_target(&mut beetles, 0, 1);
    move_toward_target(&mut beetles, 0);
}

fn set_target(beetles: &mut Beetles, subject_id: i32, target_id: i32) {
    if let Some(subject) = beetles.get_mut(&subject_id) {
        subject.target_id = target_id;
    }
}

fn move_toward_target(beetles: &mut Beetles, beetle_id: i32) {
    if let Some(subject) = beetles.get_mut(&beetle_id) {
        if let Some(target) = beetles.get(&subject.target_id) {
            // update subject position to move closer to target...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve your specific problem by performing a double lookup for the subject. First, borrow immutably from the hash map to collect the information necessary for updating the subject. Then finally update the subject using the collected information by borrowing mutably from the hash map:

```
fn move_toward_target(beetles: &mut Beetles, beetle_id: i32) {
    if let Some(subject_target_id) = beetles.get(&beetle_id).map(|b| b.target_id) {
        let mut target_xy = None; // example
        if let Some(target) = beetles.get(&subject_target_id) {
            // collect information about target relevant for updating subject
            target_xy = Some((target.x, target.y)) // example
        }
        let subject = beetles.get_mut(&beetle_id).unwrap();
        // update subject using collected information about target
        if let Some((target_x, target_y)) = target_xy{ // example
            subject.x = target_x;
            subject.y = target_y;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it is likely that you will run in similar and more complex problems with your beetles in the future, because the beetles are your central game objects, which you will likely want to reference mutably and immutably at the same time at several places in your code.
Therefore, it makes sense to wrap your beetles in [`std::cell::RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html)s, which check borrow rules dynamically at runtime. This gives you a lot flexibility when referencing beetles in your hash map:

```
fn main() {
    let mut beetles: Beetles = HashMap::new();

    beetles.insert(0, RefCell::new(Beetle::new()));
    beetles.insert(1, RefCell::new(Beetle::new()));

    set_target(&mut beetles, 0, 1);
    move_toward_target(&mut beetles, 0);
}

fn set_target(beetles: &mut Beetles, subject_id: i32, target_id: i32) {
    if let Some(mut subject) = beetles.get_mut(&subject_id).map(|b| b.borrow_mut()) {
        subject.target_id = target_id;
    }
}

fn move_toward_target(beetles: &mut Beetles, beetle_id: i32) {
    if let Some(mut subject) = beetles.get(&beetle_id).map(|b| b.borrow_mut()) {
        if let Some(target) = beetles.get(&subject.target_id).map(|b| b.borrow()) {
            //example for updating subject based on target
            subject.x = target.x;
            subject.y = target.y;
        }
    }
}
```

updated `Beetles` type:

```
type Beetles = HashMap<i32, RefCell<Beetle>>;
```

Comment: This looks really good. I'll give it a shot. Can you explain in a bit more detail what's happening under the hood that makes the first suggestion work compared to my attempt? The `map` seems to be the key, but I don't quite get what it's doing. Does it have something to do with b.target_id being `Copy`? Because intuitively I would expect b to still be borrowed during the entire scope where `subject_target_id` exists.

Comment: @anderspitman b.target_id being `Copy` in combination with `map` is exactly the reason this works. The reference to the retrieved beetle gets mapped to the `target_id`, which is copied when `Option<&Beetle>` is mapped to `Option<f32>`. If `target_id` was not `Copy`, this would result in a `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

Comment: To make sure I understand, in `move_toward_target` in the RefCell version, if you called `borrow_mut` twice (or `borrow` and `borrow_mut`) on the same element at the same time it would panic?

Comment: @anderspitman Yes, the borrow rules stay the same. Violating these rules results in panics instead of compile time errors when using `borrow` and `borrow_mut`. There also exist the non-panicing variants `try_borrow` and `try_borrow_mut` which allow you to recover from failed attempts to borrow a value.

Comment: Oh nice. That was my next question. Should have just checked the reference. Thanks for your help